# Is it Possible to Program AntMiner S9 or Other ASIC Miners?

Tags: mining-hardware, miner-configuration, asic, antminer

Is it possible to program the AntMiner S9 or other ASIC miners?

For example, let's say I only want it to try nonces from 1 to 1 million (instead of all 4 billion possibilities) would it be possible to somehow modify the software on the machine to do this? (please don't ask me why I want to do this, I just want to know if something like this is possible)

If it's possible, what programming language would I use?

Finally, would doing this (significantly) reduce the hash rate of the miner?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. To do so, you will need to modify the firmware and install your own firmware onto the S9. The source code for the firmware is available [on Github](https://github.com/bitmaintech/Antminer_firmware). The firmware is really a lightweight operating system and includes software such as CGMiner preinstalled. Those preinstalled software are probably what you will need to modify, and those are likely written in C/C++.

Since what you want to modify effects the data that is hashed, it should not effect the hashrate at all.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, this should be possible. I do not know the specific details of what is required but make the presumption that somewhere running on the embedded Linux there is a configuration file for a program that drives the thing.

I do not imagine that it would negatively affect the hash rate.